# Nuance of もらう in 毎日使ってもらえるものがいい

Tags: grammar, nuances, giving-and-receiving

I read this sentence in a listening exam script from a past paper and I was just wondering what purpose the てもらう serves here. The conversation is as follows;

> M: 先生の誕生日に何かあげませんか。
>
> F: いいですね。毎日使ってもらえるものがいいですね。

Is the nuance something like ' something we can have him use everyday....' ?

Would the phrase not work fine without もらう? For example: 毎日使えるものがいいですね。

Thanks in advance!
よろしくお願いします！

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent of もらう in English, and "have someone do ～" is just one of the "hacks" to translate this もらう into English. In this case, they are expecting Sensei will use the gift *voluntarily*, so "we can have him use" may sound off (correct me if I'm wrong).

Nevertheless, this もらう is there because they (M & F) think they will feel happy and thankful if Sensei uses the gift. It may be hard to translate this into English, but it *is* important in Japanese.

毎日使えるもの also makes perfect sense in this context, but it may sound like they are not thinking about Sensei at this moment (i.e., "something **(any)one** can use every day"). If they are thinking specifically about Sensei, including his/her sex, personality or hobby (i.e., "something **he/she** can use every day"), 毎日使ってもらえるもの would sound more natural in Japanese.