# What does てもらえたら嬉しいmean?

Tags: grammar, verbs, て-form, set-phrases

> 僕の漫画がたくさんの人に楽しんで読んでもらえたら嬉しいです。

I know 楽しんで読む means “to read with pleasure”, but I’m not sure about もらえたら嬉しいです. I’ve interpreted it as a grammar constitution that means “I’ll be glad/happy if you could……” So those the sentence mean “I’ll be happy if a lot of people can enjoy reading my manga”?

Comment: Do you mean that what you are not sure is what the verb もらう does in the sentence?

Comment: Yes, I don’t know if it’s a set grammar or if it gives the meaning of to receive

Comment: See: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/77406/7810